# How can I create an "interactive" grid in Unity2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to game development and I'm struggling with this concept.  I'm trying to create a grid (let's call it 4x4) in which one grid cell is "Active" (i.e. has the player on it) and I want the player to be able to click on an adjacent cell to move the player there and call that cell the new active cell.

Is it best to create this grid programmatically or can I use sprites?  I assume I have to keep track of the active cell using arrays, but is there a way Unity can do this for me?  Also how can I make sure the player is clicking on an adjacent cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity will not magically do this for you. Though there may be something in the asset store which specifically provides this functionality, it's not something that complex to implement on your own.

**2 suggested approaches**
The approach I would take is to have a central location for the array that holds the data of the squares. The squares would need to know which index they are in the array or you would need a way to calculate this mathematically based upon their physical coordinates. The central location that holds the board would also keep track of the index of which spot the player is on. You can then, upon clicking a tile, check and see if the index of the tile is adjacent to the index of the player. If you use a 1D array to keep track of the squares, you can use basic math like adding/subtracting `rowSize` from `index` to check immediately above/below it and `index % rowSize` - comparing it to zero or `rowSize-1` to make sure your index calculations don't wrap off the left/right sides of the board. You can use a 2D array for this instead but I found 1D easier for this. I've personally taken this approach for several board games. It's independent on the size of the grid, and if you generate the board dynamically via a script, it's easy to tag the squares with their appropriate index.

Another option is to use raycasting. When a tile is clicked on, create a RayCast from the center of that tile in all directions and see if it hits the player.

Honestly the second solution sounds a lot simpler but I'd take the first approach. That way you have far more insight into the state of the board as well as the ability to manipulate the board with much more flexibility.